# Ionic nested looping JSON Array

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I need a help in this code.

```
private initializeOptions(): void {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.sidemenus.length; ++i) {
      this.options.push({
        displayName: this.sidemenus[i].category,
        subItems: [{
            displayNamesub: 'Watch Store',
            component: MainshopPage
          }]
      });
    }
  }
```

in this code, I want to set the

```
 subItems: [{
                displayNamesub: 'Watch Store',
                component: MainshopPage
              }]
```

on the loop.
actually, i want to loop the `displayNamesub` value.

tried this:

```
 private initializeOptions(): void {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.sidemenus.length; ++i) {
          this.options.push({
            displayName: this.sidemenus[i].category,
for (var j = 0; i <this.sidemenus[i].subs.length;++j) {
            subItems: [{
            displayName: this.sidemenus[i].subs[j].subcategory,
                component: MainshopPage
              }]
}
          });
        }
      }
```

but it didn't work.
I need help to loop the `subItems`

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "category":"Accessories & Moments",
    "subs": [
      {
        "subcategory":"'Watch Store"
      },
      {
        "subcategory":"Premium Fragments"
      },
      {
        "subcategory":"Confectioneries"
      }
    ]
  }
...............................................
]
```

I take data from the JSON
please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private initializeOptions(): void {
    for(let i =0; i < this.sidemenus.length; ++i) {
      this.myArray.push({'displayName': this.sidemenus[i].category,"subItems":[]});
      for (let j=0; j < this.sidemenus[i].subs.length; ++j) {
        this.myArray[i].subItems.push({'displayName': this.sidemenus[i].subs[j].subcategory,'component': 'MainshopPage'});
      }
    }
    console.log('myArray',this.myArray);
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.myArray))
    this.options = this.myArray;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
let myArray:any = [];


for (var i = 0; i < this.sidemenus.length; ++i) {
      myArray.push({
       'displayName' : this.sidemenus[i].category,
       'subItems' : []
      })

      for (var j = 0; j < this.sidemenus[i].subs.length; ++j) {
         myArray[i].subItems[j].push({
            'displayName' : this.sidemenus[i].subs[j].subcategory,
            'component' : 'MainshopPage'
         })
      }
}

console.log('myArray',myArray);

this.options = myArray;
```

Comment: solution Pt Ltd this code is not working
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'subs' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subs' of undefined
    at MyApp.webpackJsonp.102.MyApp.initializeOptions (app.component.ts:377)
    at app.component.ts:147
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:4149)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)

Comment: your this.sidemenus is [
  {
    "category":"Accessories & Moments",
    "subs": [
      {
        "subcategory":"'Watch Store"
      },
      {
        "subcategory":"Premium Fragments"
      },
      {
        "subcategory":"Confectioneries"
      }
    ]
  }
] .........?

Comment: this.sidemeu

[{"category":"Accessories & Moments","subs":[{"subcategory":"'Watch Store"},{"subcategory":"Premium Fragments"},{"subcategory":"Confectioneries"}]},{"category":"Kids Club","subs":[{"subcategory":"Watch Store"},{"subcategory":"Confectioneries"}]},{"category":"Women's Choice","subs":[{"subcategory":"Watch Store"},{"subcategory":"Confectioneries"}]},{"category":"Wanderlust","subs":[{"subcategory":"Watch Store"},{"subcategory":"Confectioneries"}]},{"category":"Spa and Saloon","subs":[{"subcategory":"Confectioneries"},{"subcategory":"Watch Store "}]}]